# Using a tikz figure in an IEEE paper

Tags: tikz-pgf, ieeetran, ieee-style

I'm trying to include a `tikz` figure in a IEEE paper. I have the `IEEE.cls`, and `IEEE.bib` files in my current directory, but I can't seem to compile with `pdflatex`. I've used `tikz` successfully before, and I've followed my old examples, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) As the problem currently stands, it would be difficult (impossible) to reproduce your problem and therefore assess what could be wrong. As such, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that clearly illustrates your problem.

Comment: There may be a tagging problem here. You say that you're using IEEE.cls but have tagged this as IEEEtran (corresponding to IEEEtran.cls). I tried a simple TikZ picture using IEEEtran without issues. Make sure that your TeX distribution is up to date, and consider using IEEEtran as your document class.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what are you doing?, and also the link to your `IEEE.cls`. I found [this one](http://mocha-java.uccs.edu/ieee/ieeeftp/ieee.cls) in [the internet](http://mocha-java.uccs.edu/ieee/), and I was able to compile a simple TikZ example without problem. So, more information will be needed.

Comment: As far as I know, `IEEE.cls` is now obsolete. With or without TikZ, please use the [`ieeetran`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a PDF of your drawing, with the `standalone` class. Then put the image in your article using `\includegraphics` nested into a `figure` environment.

Comment: Whilst this solves the immediate problem, it doesn't really answer the implied question; why doesn't this document class play well with TikZ?

Comment: @Mark S. Everitt In these cases I always say this to myself: "Even if I tweak the class, or if I find a fancy solution that goes into my preamble, this will remain on my computer; the editor has his/her own workflow that most probably will not fit with my solution."

Comment: Oh, as far as submissions are concerned, it's a given that they have to be with images and not TikZ. Still doesn't answer the implied question. In any case, it'd be better to use TikZ with externalisation turned on to generate separate graphics so that the format of the document class is preserved without having to do it all manually.

Comment: Thanks you guys, I had actually forgotten that I had asked this question until it came up again. I'll follow your suggestions. Also, thanks for the information about IEEEtran.cls, I didn't realize that IEEE.cls was obsolete.

Comment: When I used IEEEtran.cls everything worked out just beautifully. I was able to use TikZ to my heart's content.